# How to stop touch event passing through textview which is not clickable

Tags: android, touch

I have an Imageview which has touch listener. over the image, I have two text views which are clickable, text1 and text2. text2 is not clickable in the start. when the user clicks the text1 then text2 become clickable and focusable true.

```
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
```

But when the user clicks the text2 which is not clickable in the start then touch passes to image view and the action performed which is applied at the image. I need to stop the touch behind the text2.

Answer (score 0):

in your touch listener for the imageView wrap your code around the following condition:

```
if (text1.isClickable() && text2.isClickable()) {
    //do  what you want with the imageView here
}
```

this makes sure that the imageView will not trigger an event unless both TextViews are clickable first

or

```
if (!text2.isClickable()){
        //do nothing
    } else {
        //do something
    }
```